# Error en metodo Include LinQ: No se puede cargar el tipo 'System.Data.Entity.DbExtensions'

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Tengo una aplicación de *WindowsAplication* en *C#*, está desarrollada en **N-Capas**. El método en la capa de datos para obtener una tabla no daba problemas:

```
public List<styh_m_005_cultivo> GetAll()
{
    using (var context = new TermometroDbContext())
    {
        return (
            from entity in context.styh_m_005_cultivo
            select entity
        ).ToList();
    }
}
```

Pero al agregar método `include`:

```
public List<styh_m_005_cultivo> GetAll()
{
    using (var context = new TermometroDbContext())
    {
        return (
            from entity in context.styh_m_005_cultivo
            select entity
        ).Include(c => c.styh_m_006_agricultor)
         .Include(c => c.styh_p_004_recinto).ToList();
    }
}
```

Se produce un `System.TypeLoadException`:

> No se puede cargar el tipo `System.Data.Entity.DbExtensions` del ensamblado `EntityFramework`, `Version=6.0.0.0`, `Culture=neutral`, `PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es un conflicto de versiones entre EF 5.0 y EF 6.0, elimina la referencia al ensamblado System.Data.Entity y vuelvela a generar para Entity Framework 6.0 (regenerala con NuGet), también borra cualquier linea como esta:

```
Using System.Data.Entity.DbExtensions;
```

ya que ese namespace cambio de EF 5.0 a EF 6.0.

Comment: Este problema lo solucione enviando como parametro un string del nombre de la clase poco, en vez de enviarle es tipo de la clase en el mismo metodo "Include()", quedo asi:                                             
 public List<styh_m_005_cultivo> GetAll()
        {
            using (var context = new TermometroDbContext())
            {
                return (from entity in 
 context.styh_m_005_cultivo.Include("styh_p_004_recinto").Include("styh_m_006_agricultor")
                        select entity).ToList();
            }
        }